# How to force a target platform update in eclipse when adding an osgi bundle

Tags: eclipse, osgi, target-platform

We have an osgi project in eclipse. Whenever I add a bundle to a directory used in the  target definition (using gradle to retrieve the jar from a maven repository), I have to manually update the target definition/platform. Is there a possibility to force eclipse to update/refresh the target platform during a build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that it is possible to have the Eclipse incremental build automatically react on changes to the target definition file. This may be possible though, and could be requested as [enhancement from the Eclipse PDE project](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=PDE).

Refreshing the target definition in every incremental build would not be a good idea, given that the resolution takes several seconds.

Comment: That's a pity. Sure refreshing is not necessary every build. Thx for your answer.